# Azure VM Scale Set not accessible through Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, vnet

I have followed every step of this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/quick-create-portal. Every parameter is the same except for region. In my case I use Southeast Asia. Also I use my own image which is just Ubuntu with NGINX installed on it without any further configuration.

Now, when I try to access load balancer frontend IP, it always times out. Everytime.

I tried to access the website in one of the scale-set instance from another VM (not in scale-set) in the same vnet and it works perfectly fine.

I also tried to change the load balancer backend pool to use individual VM instances (created from the same image, not in the scale-set), and it worked perfectly fine.

Lastly, I also tried to create inbound NAT rule and forward the traffic to one of the VM (again, created from the same image, not in the scale-set). Once again, works perfectly fine.

Only if the backend pool is VMSS that's giving me trouble.

Comment: Hello @BagasWahyuHidayah ,If the answer was helpful, Could you please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing the same step and MS document followed by you on my environment and faced the same issue of not able to access the VM's through the Frontend IP of the Load balancer.

[image]

My VM image (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Nginx installed):

[image]

---

To solve the issue , you can follow the below steps post creation of VMSS or while creating the VMSS.

1. **While deploying your VMSS :**

   In networking tab after you have selected the vnet to be used. Click
   on edit button to do the changes to the nic just allow selected
   ports (HTTPS).

   [image]

   After this is done , you will be successfully able to access the
   VMSS instances using load balancer.

### OR

2. If you have already created the VMSS then go to
   `VMSS>>Netowrking>>InboundRules>>Add inbound rule` as shown below:

   [image]

**Result:**

After the above port is added , you should be able to use the load balancer public IP .

[image]